# Get data from SQL Server with Excel vba and modify some of them then update the table

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I have a SQL Server table with some row (max 6000). With Excel vba, I can create a query and the results can show in a sheet.

Next I can change some record in the worksheet.

After all I can make a copy from the original sheet and after some cells changed I compare all the cells and I can update in the SQL Server database only the different cells.

My question is there a simpler way to do this?

Maybe after I leave a cells the vba compare the before/after content and make an update if required?

Thanks your opinions!

Comment: Sure - that sounds reasonable.  Did you try either of those?

Comment: just in my brain yet :) (as usual)

Comment: For 6000 rows as long as each row has a unique key it would be easier to re-query each row and check for updates, then update the DB as needed.

Comment: and how can I check for updates? compare row by row and update it if they are different? Is it a command to compare two sql row?

Comment: That depends on the details of your situation: is there a primary key? How many columns?  Is there an audit column? Do updates need to be "live" (as soon as a change is made), or can they be batched (press a button when done updating)   Will there be >1 person editing records at the same time? Etc etc

Comment: Updates need to be live and maybe more Than one user use the db. at same time. The table has 6 columns and no primary key yet. (But the db is not finished yet so it is possible to change anything).

Comment: Start by getting a primary key set up and add some audit columns (or use a separate audit table and store the "transaction id" in your table).  You don't want to stomp over other people's updates with your own changes if you'd queried out the record before they made their changes, so you need to be checking the "last updated" field and comparing it with your copy of the record.  Depending on your data also consider creating an "audit" table which tracks updates and keeps a record of any changes.

Answer (score 0):

This is the VBA event you should use to catch if a cell is changed: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-change-event-excel

If you don't want to spend much time on it, I have created an Excel AddIn which updates data from Excel to SQL Server. It is a commercial product, but if it is a one time job there is a fully functional 14-day trial which you can download from 
https://sqlspreads.com

Comment: And this method is not too slow? In every cell check the change event and if changed run an SQL update? (of course just for that value or max for the row). This way the SQL update run even if I just in the cell not just if the cells value changed.

Comment: If you only get the data from one row and do the update to a table with an index so the update is fast it would probably be possible to do on the fly, but it will add a small delay that would be noticeable by the user. 

Another alternative would be to store the changes in an array at every cell change and then add a button where the user can push all the updates to the database in a batch.